# How to optimise list view with multiple layouts

Tags: android

I am trying to determine the best way to have a single listview contains different rows styles. I know how to create a custom row + custom array adapter to support a custom row for the entire list view. But how can one listview support many different row styles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you know how many types of layout you would have - it's possible to use those methods.

getViewTypeCount() - this methods returns information how many types of rows do you have in your list

getItemViewType(int position) - returns information which layout type you should use based on position

Then you inflate layout only if it's null and determine type using getItemViewType.

Look at [this tutorial](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296) for further information.

To achieve some optimizations in structure that you've described in comment I would suggest:

- Storing views in object called ViewHolder. It would increase speed because you won't have to call findViewById() every time in getView method. See [List14 in API demos](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html).
- Create one generic layout that will conform all combinations of properties and hide some elements if current position doesn't have it.

I hope that will help you. If you could provide some XML stub with your data structure and information how exactly you want to map it into row, I would be able to give you more precise advise. By pixel.

Answer (score 0):

Just create an attribute and myListView.addView('your inflate view')

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
RelativeView myCustomView =(RelativeView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.task_since_user);
myListView.addView(myCustomView);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write you custom adapter which extends BasaAdapter. NOTE: viewTypeCount(). Then you can use condition to check and assign different views

```
private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
public static final int ITEM_TYPE_ONE = 1;
public static final int ITEM_TYPE_TWO = 2;
@Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return (position % 2 == 0) ? ITEM_TYPE_ONE : ITEM_TYPE_TWO;
    }

@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        int itemTypeId = getItemViewType(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            if (itemTypeId == ITEM_TYPE_ONE) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_one, parent, false);
            } else {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_two, parent, false);
            }
        }
}
```

}